# Git pull from Bitbucket server

Tags: php, git, apache, ssh, bitbucket

I have a problem with running git pull from a php script on a remote server. I have looked at a lot of different sources to make it work but none works for me. So what have I done so far:

- Created the pub and private key for Apache:

  ```
  mkdir /var/www/.ssh
  sudo chown -R apache:nobody /var/www/.ssh
  su - apache -c "ssh-keygen -t rsa"
  ```
- Then I have put my public key on Bitbucket.
- Then I run the command:

  ```
  sudo -u apache git pull
  ```

Everything works fine.

After all that I wrote a simple `sh` script which I call from `PHP`.

1. The .sh script:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   git pull
   ```
2. and the PHP script:

   ```
   <?php    
   $cmd="./gitpullsc.sh 2>&1";
   echo exec($cmd);
   ?>
   ```

I run the php script from a web browser and I get back this:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Then I tried to add to the script `whoami` (to see if the user running the php script is the right one) and I get apache. So everything ok.

I use Red Hat linux.

### Any help appreciated :)

UPDATE

Ok, maybe I found the problem, but still looking for the solution.

I run again the `sudo -u apache git pull` and now I am getting asked for the private key passphrase again.

But if I run the command `ssh-add -l` I get:

> 2048 **********thenumber******* /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

So I think that everything is fine. But the problem maybe is that i run the ssh agent this way:

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
```

---

UPDATE

Yes, the problem was really the passphrase prompt. I still don't know how to fix it, but for now I just left the passphrase blank and it works...

Comment: Interesting situation!

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: No I don't. It is not even installed. I will install it, so what do I do after the installation?

Comment: @MarkoJurinčič did you leave your SSH private key un-encrypted (i.e. with a blank passphrase) on your remote server? That is not as secure as it could be, it's like leaving your password sitting in a plain-text file on the remote server. If someone manages to break into it, they can steal the private key and start using it to login to all of your SSH accounts that have the corresponding public key. A passphrase protects against this by encrypting the private key, making it useless without a passphrase.

Comment: Yes I know that is not secure, but I still can't make it work with a passphrase. When we'll switch to production (now we are still developing the product) I'll set back the passphrase and pulling the code from the terminal on the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question. I really wanted to add a comment referring to that answer but I do not have enough points to add a comment.

The idea is use start ssh-agent once and load your keys to it. Later, in your .bashrc, you update environment variables so that it points to the same ssh-agent (that already has the keys).

Please look at [trying to deploy using Capistrano but ssh-agent on my remote machine doesn't keep my identity loaded so the git command fails; why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027327/trying-to-deploy-using-capistrano-but-ssh-agent-on-my-remote-machine-doesnt-kee)

Answer (score 0):

You need the manager for the `ssh-agent` called `keychain`

> yum install keychain

If not in the official RHEL repo you can get it from the [RPM forge](http://repoforge.org/) repository. To test start new user session and manually load the key to the ssh-agent.
Assuming your generated key is called id_dsa and is located inside the ~/.ssh/ dir.

```
$ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

However that still might not solve you browser problem since that is different user session for the apache user.